# How to deploy react client and express server to GCP?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, npm, google-cloud-platform, yaml

I have an app that has 2 directories
client (React app) and server (Node Express API).

I created a GCP project and deployed my React App with the `app.yaml` file:

```
runtime: nodejs14
service: default

handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: client/build/static

  - url: /assets
    static_dir: client/build/assets

  - url: /(.*\.(json|ico|js))$
    static_files: client/build/\1
    upload: client/build/.*\.(json|ico|js)$

  - url: .*
    static_files: client/build/index.html
    upload: client/build/index.html
```

Which is the `default` service.

So I want to also add my Express server as API server, which I created another `app.yaml` file in the server directory as

```
runtime: nodejs14

service: api
```

After deploying my server directory, its still not running?

On my local machine I do `npm` run dev (which runs both client and backend script) and works fine.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean about your API server not running? App Engine does not keep an instance running if there are no requests (unless you specify it). I suggest learning more about GAE's scaling type. By default, it should be automatic. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-instances-are-managed

Comment: You have mentioned that 'After deploying my server directory, its still not running.'. Does that mean you are getting some error? If yes, can you please mention what error exactly you are getting?